# Android studio last edit location on ReOpen

Tags: android, ide, edit, restart

Does anyone know how to save the exact line of code that was being worked on before closing Android studio? On open it will show the last code pane but defaults at the top. Is there a way to save exact state so that on opening again you are back there?

I've tried plug-ins like lastEdited but they also just show the last page not last page and line edited
Ctrl-Shift-backspace works but only when already in session and not on reopen
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, good news. after updating Android studio to Arctic Fox It now by default opens the IDE on last edit location including the line that was being worked on. Thanks Google